# Injected Service in a Service is undefined in tests

Tags: angular, angular-test

I injected a service in the constructor using ServiceLocator.injector. When I ran Unit Tests, it shows an error "TypeError: Cannot read 'environmentWeb' of undefined". environmentWeb() is a method of the service I injected in the constructor.

I tried putting the Service in the providers, and I tried using TestBed.get(Service) to inject the Service in the test case, but non worked

ReportService.ts

```
export class ReportService extends ReportsCommonDataObject {
    private dataLoaded: boolean = false;
    protected http: HttpClient;
    protected performanceService: PerformanceService;
    protected performanceSecondLevelService: PerformanceSecondLevelService;
    protected sharedService: SharedService;
    protected utilService: UtilService;
    constructor() {
        super();

        setTimeout(() => {
            this.performanceService = ServiceLocator.injector.get<PerformanceService>(PerformanceService);
            this.performanceSecondLevelService = ServiceLocator.injector.get<PerformanceSecondLevelService>(PerformanceSecondLevelService);
            this.sharedService = ServiceLocator.injector.get<SharedService>(SharedService);
            this.utilService = ServiceLocator.injector.get<UtilService>(UtilService);
            this.http = ServiceLocator.injector.get<HttpClient>(HttpClient);     
        });
    }
```

report.service.spec.ts:

```
describe('ReportService', () => {

    let reportService: ReportService;
    let httpTestingController: HttpTestingController;    
    let sharedService: SharedService;

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            providers: [
                SharedService,
                HttpClient,
                ReportService,
                PerformanceService,
                PerformanceSecondLevelService,
                MatDialog,
            ],
            imports: [
                AppModule,
                BrowserModule,
                HttpClientTestingModule
            ],
        }).compileComponents()

        // Inject the http service and test controller for each test
        httpTestingController = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
        reportService = TestBed.get(ReportService);
        sharedService = TestBed.get(SharedService);

    });
```

Comment: May be UtilService that you forgot to put in providers?

Comment: Is your query solved?

Comment: I tried putting the UtilService in the providers, but still getting an error.

Comment: Which service contains this method/property `environmentWeb `?

Comment: The SharedService

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
reportService = TestBed.get(ReportService);\
sharedService = TestBed.get(SharedService);
```

try this:

```
reportService = new ReportService();\
sharedService = new SharedService();
```